# Does the standard define an alias to Result<T, dyn std::error::Error>?

Tags: rust, error-handling, alias

I'm aware of the [`Result` aliasing idiom](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/error/result/result_alias.html), where you define an alias for a custom error type. The classic example appears to be [`std::io::Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/type.Result.html), which may return a [`std::io::Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Error.html):

```
pub type Result<T> = Result<T, std::io::Error>;
```

Although I write my custom error types, the general case arises often, specially on the top level functions (which handle all types of errors). I noticed I'm using the standard [`Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html) trait now and then, so that I write `Result<T, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>` repeatedly.

Then it made me wonder: does the standard define an alias to `Result<T, Box<dyn Error>>` somewhere?

If not, is there any recommended practice in dealing with it?

Comment: you mean `pub type Result<T> = Result<T, dyn std::io::Error>;` ? BTW, I disadvise both type alias of Result and dynamic error

Comment: @Stargateur `std::io::Error` is a type, not a trait.

Comment: replace by std::error::Error

Answer (score 3):

The type `dyn std::error::Error` is a *trait object*, and can refer to any type implementing the `Error` trait. This means the type doesn't have a known size at compile time; it's called a *dynamically sized type*.

As a consequence, the type `Result<T, dyn std::error::Error>` is also dynamically sized, since it needs to be able to hold any suitable error type. This means you cannot directly use this type in most contexts, and specifically not as the return type of a function, so it's not particularly useful.

It's possible you mean `Result<T, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>`, which puts the trait object behind a pointer, so the `Result` type itself has a known size.

> Does the standard define an alias to `Result<T, std::error::Error>`?

The Rust language is not specified by a standard. Rust has a *standard library*, but it does not contain an alias for `Result<T, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>`. If you need such an alias, you can simply add it to your code yourself.

You may also be interested in the [`anyhow` crate](https://docs.rs/anyhow/), which defines an `anyhow::Error` type that any error type implementing `std::error::Error` can be converted into, and the `anyhow::Result` type alias that defaults to this error type. The crate is quite widley used and comes as close to a "standard" way of handling arbitrary errors as it gets.

As a side note, the type alias definition

```
pub type Result<T> = Result<T, std::io::Error>;
```

you quoted in your question is invalid, since the Result on the right-hand side resolves to the `Result` currently being defined, so it's cyclic. If you want to alias the `Result` type from the prelude with an alias also called `Result`, you need to write

```
pub type Result<T> = std::result::Result<T, std::io::Error>;
```

instead.

Comment: Yes, I mean with the `Box`. I edited the question again.